# Valid Function Declaration

Tags: c++, methods, declaration

I have an abstract C++ Question and I'm having an argument with someone about this:

Which one of these could be a valid function declaration:

```
int f ( int i=0, int j );
int f (int j, void k);
int f (int i, int u=0 );
int f (int * = 0);
```

Comment: Seriously? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ or your own compiler.

Comment: There are actually *two* valid function declarations in that list.

Comment: First and second are wrong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP should do the homework.

Answer (score 8):

Three of them **could** be valid. The third and fourth are clearly okay. The first **could** be valid in a broader context:

```
int f(int i, int j = 0);
int f(int i = 0, int j);
```

Function declarations are allowed to add additional default arguments, but are not allowed to repeat the previous defaults. So the second line (your first example) is okay here.

Comment: Bravo! An excellent answer, pointing to one of those strange quirks that is likely to be missed, even by many who generally know the language quite well. Truly unfortunate that it'll probably be lost because it's in response to a heavily down-voted question.

Comment: "My god" I thought.  "This author knows the darkest corners of standard."  Then I saw who the author was, oh yeah; he does.